# 2013 Check out and Edit PDF file

Tags: pdf, check-out, check-in, edit, read-only

I have some issues with Sharepoint 2013 document library, for edit/check out PDF File, only for PDF document.

I have some premiums users that absolutely need the "checkout and edit" functionnality working in Sharepoint 2013 exactly the same as Sharepoint 2010.

Let me explain my problem with my 2013 environment....
When they clicked on a PDF document, the PDF File is automatically open in the client application (that's want she need) but the "Check out and edit" option wasn't shown before..
So she's not capable to modify the document because it's read only... that's very frustrating.

The settings:
 "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" is set to YES

I verify all settings of 2010 and 2013 document lib, and they are exactly the same.

Why the behavior are different between 2010 and 2013?

Does anyone have this issues?

Thanks!

The screenshot show the check out and edit Window display by in Sharepoint 2010 librairy once PDF file is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Verify the issue does not stem from the user's browser or version.
I have seen unexplainable issues of reduced functionality with browsers that are not 32 bit IE.  Also verify that compatibility mode is active in their browser for your site(s).

Answer (score 0):

I used the Windows Explorer Integration suggestion to change the registry.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/FeatureLockdown.html?zoom_highlight=disable+sharepoint+integration#idkeyname_1_6720